# Strings addition in C Program

Tags: c

How to add an integer to the ASCII value of the characters in a string?

Example:- if the ASCII values of the characters in string `"eat"` are 101 97 116, how would I add an integer value, suppose it is 10, to each ASCII value so it changes to 111 107 126.

Can anyone write code in C for that??

Comment: simple cast to int and add

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh You don't even need to cast anything. `char` is a numeric type.

Comment: `void add(char*s,int x){while(*s)*s+++=x;}`

Comment: But, adding `10` to `'z'` (ASCII 122 ==> 132) breaks the bounds of an ASCII value. Also unclear if you are working with say `(signed) char` or `unsigned char` or `int`.

Comment: @paddy Love that `+++` - have not seen that before.

Comment: I was being cheeky: obviously it's equivalent to `*(s++) += x;`.  But `+++` looks cool and it reminds me of yesteryear when typing that could put your modem into AT-command mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to loop over each element of the char array and add 10 one by one.

```
int i;
char string[4] = "abc\0";
for(i = 0; i < string[i]; i++) {
    string[i] += 10;
}
```

Since a char is an (n bit) integer you can simply add integers to it.

Comment: Not necessarily 8-bit: check `CHAR_BIT` in `limits.h` to check for sure. Also, you don't need to manually add `\0` to the end of the string - the string literal syntax does that for you.

Comment: @Archmede it gives an error "comparison of integers of different signs:'int' and 'size_t'(aka 'unsigned int')"

Comment: @paddy Yes, it's way better not to recalculate `strlen` every time.

Comment: thnx @bob your code worked but as paddy said, drop `strlen` instead use `string[i]`

Comment: Detail: Using `string[i]` instead of `strlen(string)` is potential different functionality in this case as the loop modifies `string[]`.  BTW: code does not "loop over each element of the char array".  It does not iterate of the last element of the `string[]`, the _null character_.  Certainly that is a good thing.